# How can I modify this PHP Query to add the database value 'timestamp'?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm using the following query that another Stackoverflow user helped me with, it's completely new to me:

```
"SELECT CONCAT(u1.firstname,' ',u1.lastname) as sender,CONCAT(u2.firstname,' 
',u2.lastname) as receiver, t.points as points FROM transactions t INNER JOIN users u1 ON 
u1.id=t.sender_id INNER JOIN users u2 ON u2.id=t.receiver_id ORDER BY date DESC limit 5"
```

It's working fine, but I realized I hadn't got the value `'timestamp'` coming through from the database. How can I add `timestamp` to the query so I can echo it in my results?

`'timestamp'` is stored in the `transactions` table.

Thanks.

Comment: Which table is having `timestamp` column?

Comment: transactions is the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to just add `t.timestamp` in your query.

```
"SELECT CONCAT(u1.firstname,' ',u1.lastname) as sender,CONCAT(u2.firstname,' 
',u2.lastname) as receiver, t.points as points, t.timestamp FROM transactions t INNER JOIN users u1 ON 
u1.id=t.sender_id INNER JOIN users u2 ON u2.id=t.receiver_id ORDER BY date DESC limit 5"
```

Comment: Could have sworn I'd tried that, several different ways... Thanks mate, lifesaver.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
"SELECT CONCAT(u1.firstname,' ',u1.lastname) as sender,CONCAT(u2.firstname,' ',u2.lastname) as receiver, t.points as points, t.timestamp as timestamp FROM transactions t INNER JOIN users u1 ON u1.id=t.sender_id INNER JOIN users u2 ON u2.id=t.receiver_id ORDER BY date DESC limit 5"
```